# what's the mean about the rails rspec code`to_not be_valid`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when i user the ruby on rails to learn how to test a code use the rails `rspec`,some code i can't understand,  here is the code, it is just a code about parking  meter test.

```
db/migrate/xxxxx_create_parking.rb

class CreateParkings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

def change
    create_table :parkings do |t|
      t.string :parking_type   #guest, short-term, long-term
      t.datetime :start_at   
      t.datetime :end_at     
      t.integer :amount      

      t.integer :user_id, index: true 

app/spec/models/parking_spec.rb

    require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Parking, type: :model do
  #pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"

 describe ".validate_end_at_with_amount" do

   it "is invalid without amount" do
     parking = Parking.new( :parking_type => "guest",
                            :start_at => Time.now - 6.hours,
                            :end_at => Time.now)
      expect(parking).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without end_at" do
      parking = Parking.new( :parking_type => "guest",
                             :start_at => Time.now - 6.hours,
                             :amount => 999)
       expect(parking).to_not be_valid
     end
   end
end
```

so, what is the mean about the `to_not be_valid` and `t.integer :user_id, index: true` ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `be_valid` it is testing the `ActiveModel::Validations` of the new record, it works like `valid?` function, by putting `not_to` you mean that when i insert this record `parking = Parking.new( :parking_type => "guest",:start_at => Time.now - 6.hours,:amount => 999)` without `end_at` it shouldn't work, by this you are checking that you code works fine with invalid cases, Here is a good resource about [be_valid](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec/Rails/Matchers#be_valid-instance_method).

for the second part `t.integer :user_id` this is a command in `ActiveRecord` which add a new column/field in the table called `user_id` and 
 `index: true` puts an index on it (it is a concept in the database world which helps with retrieving records in much less time), `user_id` will be used usually as foreign key [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index).

Comment: wow, thanks, i get something!   for the code `expect(parking).to_not be_valid`,it just mean " it expect the parking is invalid "